# SQL Server Status Monitor

Tags: sql, service, monitoring

My application connects to 3 SQL servers and 5 databases simultaneously. I need to show statuses `{running|stopped|not found}` on my status bar.

Any idea/code sample that I can use here? This code should not affect the speed of application or a overhead to SQL server.

Buddhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use WMI (using the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3fkxeff.aspx) class (with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx) constructor).  You basically query the server where the sql server resides and check its status.

The example below is assuming your application is written in c#:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MSSQLSERVER", serverName); 
string status = sc.Status.ToString();
```

Comment: Those SQL servers are not running on my machine, they are from Servers on my local network, I think we cannot use this...

Comment: Yes you can use this, even when the services are on other machines. You have to have the appropriate rights on the machine where the services are running.

Comment: You can either use impersonation, or grant permissions to every user you need to run the application as.  Take a look at this page for information on the permissions needed: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_permissions.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

> "This code should not affect the speed
>   of application or a overhead to SQL
>   server"

This is a Schroedinger's Cat scenario: in order to know the current status of a given remote service or process, you must serialize a message onto the network, await a response, de-serialize the response and act upon it. All of which will require some work and resources from all machines involved.

However, that work might be done in a background thread on the caller and if not called too often, may not impact the target server(s) in any measurable way.

You can use [SMO (SQL Server Management Objects)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162547.aspx) to connect to a remote server and do pretty much anything you can do through the SQL admin tools since they use SMO to work their magic too. It's a pretty simple API and can be very powerful in the right hands.

SMO does, unsurprisingly, require that your have appropriate rights to the boxes you want to monitor. If you don't/can't have sufficient rights, you might want to ask your friendly SQL amin team to publish a simple data feed exposing some of the data you need.

HTH.

Comment: I hope this is introduced with SQL 2008, unfortunatly I am still using SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some overhead within your application when connecting (verifying connection) or failing to connect (verifying no connection) but you can prevent waiting time, by checking this asynscronously.

Comment: I would run a basic script like SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Contacts. This will check both connectivity to the database and that all the permissions etc are still ok. The overhead will be low and can be further reduced by polling/checking less often.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following SQL query to check the [status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190442.aspx) of a particular database

```
SELECT 'myDatabase status is:' AS Description, ISNULL((select state_desc FROM sys.databases WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name ='myDatabase'),'Not Found') AS [DBStatus]
```

This should have very little overhead, especially when paired with best practices like background or asynchronous threads

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure, I am the founder of [Cotega](http://www.cotega.com)

If you are interested in a service to do this, our service allows for monitoring of SQL Server uptime and performance.  In addition you can set notifications for when the database is not available, performance degrades, database size or user count issues occur, etc.